# Is there a generic and reliable solution, to make UICollectionViewCell's width wrap content?

Tags: ios, swift

I find it is very difficult, and error prone to make a horizontal scrolled `UICollectionViewCell`, to achieve wrap content capability on its content.

For instance, I have a `UICollectionViewCell`, which its only content is a `UILabel`. I need to use the following code, to make sure its width will resize based on the length of `UILabel`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    if isSizeToFitCellsNeeded {
        
        // Use 500 (Any arbitary large value will do)
        let sizeee = CGSize.init(width: 500, height: self.frame.height)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        
        let str = dataArray[indexPath.item].name
        
        // Currently, our UILabel is using font UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        // I am not sure why do I need to use UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        // in cell wrap size calculation, to make thing looks good???
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        
        let estimatedRect = NSString.init(string: str).boundingRect(with: sizeee, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : font], context: nil)
    
        // 44 is minimum touchable area based on Apple design guideline
        return CGSize.init(
            width: max(44, estimatedRect.size.width),
            height: self.frame.height)

    }
    
    return CGSize.init(width: (self.frame.width)/CGFloat(dataArray.count), height: self.frame.height)
}
```

Here's the outcome.

[image]

Even though it seems "work", the code is not reliable and not generic, as

1. A lot of magic numbers used
2. What if `UICollectionViewCell` no longer hold single `UILabel`, but multiple of different UI components?

---

If I replace `UILabel` with `UIImageView`. Suddenly, the code will break. The cell width no longer wrap to its content size. We expect all the cell size will be same, as they are showing the same icon.

[image]

I was wondering, is there a generic and reliable solution, to make UICollectionViewCell's width wrap content?

Comment: How about using horizontal stack here? In this kind of scenarios I prefer using stack views. Whatever UI elements you use (and hide others), stack will adjust its size and you can arrange cell with based on the stack view width.

Comment: Using horizontal stack might not be good for our case. As, our number of tab can be arbitrary large. By using horizontal collection view, we might utilize it's cell reusing capability, to eliminate the need of creating a huge amount of UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

For the re-usability, you may register different cells corresponding the different combination of UI elements. Then based on cell types, different sizes might be returned. For example, fixed size for the UIImageView icons, and different sizes for labels and etc.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let item = dataArray[indexPath.item]

    if item.type == .label { 
        return labelSize
    } else if item.type == .icon { 
        return iconSize    
    }

    return defaultSize
}
```

For calculating the label size, I may suggest creating a custom label by extending the `UILabel` and override its `intrinsicContentSize` property. For giving a padding regardless of font size, defining insents and calculating the new size seems to be fine. Then you will not need to calculate label during creation of cells, instead it will be defined during label creation.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
    return CGSize(width: size.width + leftPadding + rightPadding,
        height: size.height + topPadding + bottomPadding)
}
```

Comment: Hi, the proposed solution is not generic enough. What if, the cell might not contain single label or single icon. It might contains multiple labels and multiple icons?

Comment: I see, right now I am not able to find a level of abstraction you need. I will think more about it and update the answer if I can come up with new ideas. I would be happy if you share your solution in case of finding one. Good luck!